# Finding out the request address in libcurl

Tags: c, url, libcurl

I have a software that uses a libcurl version 7.59. I need to export the url that it uses and write it to the text file. Url is set by

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLoption tag, ...)
```

According to libcurl documentation the parameter type is char * ad it is being set like `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");`

Type of parameter in libcurl is `va_list arg`

I have added code in curl_easy_setopt

```
if (tag == CURLOPT_URL) {
  FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "a+");

  if (f == NULL)
  {
      printf("Error opening file!\n");
      exit(1);
  }


  int len = strlen(&arg);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      fprintf(f, "Some text: %c\n", &arg[i]);
  }





  fclose(f);
```

}

But I have some problems with encoding.

```
Some text: 
Some text: 
Some text: 
Some text: 
Some text: 
Some text:  
Some text: !
Some text: "
Some text: #
Some text: $
Some text: %
Some text: D
```

I know that i can check the address by wireshark, but I need to do it exactly this way because I will need to change this address later.
Curl code

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(struct Curl_easy *data, CURLoption tag, ...)
{
  va_list arg;
  CURLcode result;






  if(!data)
    return CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT;




  va_start(arg, tag);




  result = Curl_vsetopt(data, tag, arg);





  va_end(arg);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `&arg[i]` is totally meaningless. It's not an encoding issue.

Comment: `fprintf(f, "Some text: %c\n", &arg[i])` Whatever `arg` might be or not, an address is never printed with `%c` format specifier.

Comment: fprintf(f, "entire string: %s\n",&arg) also gives me an unreadable thing

Comment: So it is impossible to write it into the file?

Comment: I have updated code. I've pasted part from libcurl. All i need is to get value of arg and save it to text file. I am making it in curl itself.

Comment: 'arg' is not a char pointer - it is a va_list, you first need to get the char pointer using `va_arg()` and then access the string using *that* pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are amazing